# Specify decimal precision of column in a SQL Server indexed view

Tags: sql-server, decimal, precision, indexed-view

I am wondering if it's possible to override the default column precision of columns within an indexed view. The view seems to always create the columns with the largest possible precision.

A complete run-able example is below:

```
-- drop and recreate example table and view if they exist
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'ExampleIndexedView')
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[ExampleIndexedView]

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'Example')
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Example]

-- create example table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Example](
    [UserID] [int],
    [Amount] [decimal](9, 2)
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- insert sample rows
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Example] ([UserID], [Amount]) VALUES (1, 10)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Example] ([UserID], [Amount]) VALUES (2, 20)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Example] ([UserID], [Amount]) VALUES (3, 30)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Example] ([UserID], [Amount]) VALUES (1, 15)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Example] ([UserID], [Amount]) VALUES (1, 2.5)
GO

-- create indexed view
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ExampleIndexedView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
    e.UserID as UserID
    ,SUM(ISNULL(e.[Amount], 0)) as [Amount]
    ,COUNT_BIG(*) as [Count]        --Required for indexed views
FROM [dbo].[Example] e
GROUP BY 
    e.UserID
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_ExampleIndexedView]
    ON [dbo].[ExampleIndexedView]
        ([UserID])

-- show stats for view
exec sp_help [ExampleIndexedView]
```

This results in a view with the columns:

```
UserID(int, null)  
Amount(decimal(38,2), null)
```

I understand why the view would automatically use the largest possible storage type for a `SUM` column, however let's say I know that the summing of that `Amount` column will never exceed the limits of a `decimal(19, 2)` - is there a way I can force the view to create the column as `decimal(19, 2)` instead of `decimal(38, 2)`?

`decimal(38, 2)` takes 17 bytes to store, `decimal(19,2)` only takes 9 bytes. As a test I duplicated my indexed view into a regular table where I used `decimal(19,2)` and the overall storage space saving was around 40%, so it seems like it would be a worthwhile thing to do for a view that contains a large number of decimal aggregations.

Edit: Posted a complete run-able example that creates an example table, populates it with a few rows, then creates an indexed view on that table. The result is that the Amount column in the indexed view is decimal(38,2), i would like to find a way to force it to decimal(19,2) for space saving reasons.

Answer (score 0):

CAST() or CONVERT() it to your required precision

```
Select 
    UserID, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2), SUM(Amount)) as Amount, 
FROM 
    Example
GROUP BY 
    UserID
```

Comment: That does not make any difference, the indexed view still creates the column with the maximum possible decimal precision

Comment: in my test, i do get (9,2)

Comment: what version of Sql Server are you using? im using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: It looks to me like you are creating a regular view, not an indexed view as your syntax isnt correct for an indexed view. If i do it as a regular view then you are correct, the column type adjusts accordingly, but this is not the case for an indexed view. I will update my OP to include the full indexed view creation script.

Comment: Oh i didn't create the index just schemabinding the view. Just tried, with the convert() it does not allow to create the index. But the data type of the view is (9,2) .`exec sp_help [ExampleIndexedView]`

Comment: Its not for me.
`Column_name Type Computed Length Prec Scale
 Nullable TrimTrailingBlanks FixedLenNullInSource Collation

UserID int no 4 10    0     yes (n/a) (n/a) NULL

Amount decimal no 17 38    2     yes (n/a) (n/a) NULL

Count bigint no 8 19    0     yes (n/a) (n/a) NULL
`sorry not sure how to format this properly in a comment. Can you run my exact view creation and see what you get. There must be some difference between what you are doing.

Comment: or post your view + index creation creation query in your answer and i will try it on my PC and see what i get.

Comment: I have updated my OP to include a full run-able example script to demonstrate the issue. I would be interested to see if it is doing the same thing for you, seeing as you said you were getting a different result with the sample you made.